# Straight line connector displays as an arrow

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Lately I've noticed on one of my spreadsheets that my straight line connector and my curly brackets display as arrows (ie. with a little arrow-head on one end).

I am baffled and befuddled as to why/how this changed. It appears to be only on the one spreadsheet so it must be a file-specific setting.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The straight line connector and curly brackets display as arrows (ie. with a little arrow-head on one end) when the font selected is "**Wingdings3**".  Change the font other than "wingdings" and you should be able to see the straight line connectors and curly brackets.